# Error catching in a java class

Tags: java, android

I having a problem with catching errors on my android application. It's just meant for practice but here is the following issue:

I have a class which takes the values from the screen and text boxes. It then converts them into a day class which has a `Start`, `Break` , and `Finish`.

The `GetHours()` method then splits a value such as 12:30 into 12 and .5 (12.5) and feeds back how many hours are worked with a simple formula `HoursWorked = (Finish - Start) - Lunch;`

My question is if i use a class like this will i be able to catch an error such as starting work at 45:78 (impossible) and if so where do i catch the error in the main activity or in the class?

Any help is Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw the error where the calculation is being made. Do a check after calculating that the time is valid and return it if it is. If it isn't, throw an exception. The object calling for this number can then be surrounded with try/catch, and throw the error that says that the number is invalid

Example:

```
// in getHours() :

double hours = 12.5;

if(hours < 13) { //check to make sure hours is valid/correct
    return hours;
}
else{
    throw new Exception("Hours value of " + hours + " is not valid");
}

// in main class:

try{
    hours = getHours();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This answer is pretty good because it addresses the root cause of the problem. However I would suggest adding a simple try catch block example for the OP.

Comment: Hi , i just added the code there! I didn't see this till after i posted the code. Thanks for the example though ill give it a try now!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your logic is wrong while converting time in format hour:min, for example  output of "starting work at 45:78" should be 46:18. I would suggest you to look at the logic of method getHour and correct the calculation instead of thinking to consider value 45:78 as error.